# JavaFX Coloured Table Row

Tags: javafx

I have a Table which has a row factory attached to it to colour some of the rows. The issue is that the rows only change colour after you scroll the table up and down. What do I need to do to get the background colour to display when the table is initiated?

There is a video here: https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cFQYlEqPSv

```
ObservableList<SupplierProductOTIF> orderData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

orderTable.setRowFactory(row -> new TableRow<SupplierProductOTIF>() {

    @Override
    public void updateItem(SupplierProductOTIF item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (item == null || empty) {
            setStyle("");
        } else {
            if (item.isException()) {
                //We apply now the changes in all the cells of the row
                for (int i = 0; i < getChildren().size(); i++) {
                    ((Labeled) getChildren().get(i)).setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .25);");
                }
            } else if (item.getQtyToOrder() > 0) {
                //We apply now the changes in all the cells of the row
                for (int i = 0; i < getChildren().size(); i++) {
                    ((Labeled) getChildren().get(i)).setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, .25);");
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < getChildren().size(); i++) {
                    ((Labeled) getChildren().get(i)).setStyle("");
                }
                setStyle("");
            }
        }
    }
});

orderTable.setItems(orderData);

for (SupplierProductOTIF product : supplier.getOtifSupplierData()) {
    if(product.getQtyToOrder() > 0 || product.isException()) {
       orderData.add(0, product);
    } else {
       orderData.add(product);
    }
}
```

Edit: Here's the full code of my class

```
public class ReplenishmentPopupController extends ReportController implements Initializable {

    private SupplierOTIF supplier;
    private SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy");

    @FXML
    private TableView orderTable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn productName;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn sku;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn currentStock;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn maxLeadTime;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn qtyToOrder;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn qtyOnOrder;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn nextOrderDate;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<SupplierProductOTIF, LocalDate> stockUntilDate;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn daysStock;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn averageStockDailySales;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn daysOfStockToHold;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn daysOfStockToOrder;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn incost;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn supplierCost;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn orderCost;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn supplierPreference;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn productStatus;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn boxQty;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn minimumOrderQty;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn qtyRequired;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn rrs;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn rank;
    @FXML
    private Button raisePurchaseOrderButton;
    @FXML
    private Label supplierLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label orderValueLabel;

    private ObservableList<SupplierProductOTIF> orderData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        initOrderTable();
    }

    public void initOrderTable() {

        orderTable.setEditable(true);

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

        sku.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("sku"));
        sku.prefWidthProperty().bind(orderTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.05));

        productName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("name"));
        productName.prefWidthProperty().bind(orderTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.1));

        currentStock.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("freeStock"));
        currentStock.prefWidthProperty().bind(orderTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.05));

        averageStockDailySales.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("averageForecastDailySales"));
        averageStockDailySales.prefWidthProperty().bind(orderTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.05));
        //averageStockDailySales.setVisible(false);

        daysStock.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("daysStock"));
        daysStock.prefWidthProperty().bind(orderTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.05));

        stockUntilDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("stockUntilDate"));
        stockUntilDate.prefWidthProperty().bind(orderTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.1));
        stockUntilDate.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<SupplierProductOTIF, LocalDate>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(LocalDate date, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(date, empty);
                if (empty || date == null) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setText(formatter.format(date));
                }
            }
        });

        maxLeadTime.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("maxLeadTime"));
        maxLeadTime.prefWidthProperty().bind(orderTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.05));

        qtyToOrder.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("qtyToOrder"));
        qtyToOrder.prefWidthProperty().bind(orderTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.075));
        qtyToOrder.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new StringConverter<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Integer object) {
                return object.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public Integer fromString(String string) {
                return Integer.parseInt(string);
            }

        }));

        qtyToOrder.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<SupplierProductOTIF, Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<SupplierProductOTIF, Integer> t) {
                    ((SupplierProductOTIF) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                            t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setQtyToOrder(t.getNewValue());
                    updatePurchaseOrderValue();
            }
        });

        daysOfStockToHold.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("daysOfStockRequired"));
        daysOfStockToHold.prefWidthProperty().bind(orderTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.05));

        qtyOnOrder.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("qtyOutStanding"));
        qtyOnOrder.prefWidthProperty().bind(orderTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.075));
        //qtyOnOrder.setVisible(false);

        minimumOrderQty.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("minimumOrderQty"));
        minimumOrderQty.prefWidthProperty().bind(orderTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.05));
        //minimumOrderQty.setVisible(false);

        boxQty.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("boxQty"));
        boxQty.prefWidthProperty().bind(orderTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.05));

        qtyRequired.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("qtyRequired"));
        qtyRequired.prefWidthProperty().bind(orderTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.05));

        daysOfStockToOrder.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("daysOfStockToOrder"));
        daysOfStockToOrder.prefWidthProperty().bind(orderTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.05));
        //daysOfStockToOrder.setVisible(false);

        incost.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("incost"));
        incost.prefWidthProperty().bind(orderTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.05));
        //incost.setVisible(false);

        supplierCost.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("supplierCost"));
        supplierCost.prefWidthProperty().bind(orderTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.05));
        supplierCost.setVisible(false);

        orderCost.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("orderCost"));
        orderCost.prefWidthProperty().bind(orderTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.05));
        //orderCost.setVisible(false);

        supplierPreference.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("supplierPreference"));
        supplierPreference.prefWidthProperty().bind(orderTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.05));
        supplierPreference.setVisible(false);

        productStatus.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("productStatus"));
        productStatus.prefWidthProperty().bind(orderTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.05));

        rrs.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("rank"));
        rrs.prefWidthProperty().bind(orderTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.05));

        rank.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("productRanking"));
        rank.prefWidthProperty().bind(orderTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.05));

        orderTable.setRowFactory(row -> new TableRow<SupplierProductOTIF>() {

            @Override
            public void updateItem(SupplierProductOTIF item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setStyle("");
                } else {
                    if (item.isException()) {
                        //We apply now the changes in all the cells of the row
                        for (int i = 0; i < getChildren().size(); i++) {
                            ((Labeled) getChildren().get(i)).setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .25);");
                        }
                    } else if (item.getQtyToOrder() > 0) {
                        //We apply now the changes in all the cells of the row
                        for (int i = 0; i < getChildren().size(); i++) {
                            ((Labeled) getChildren().get(i)).setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, .25);");
                        }
                    } else if (item.getQtyToOrder() == 0 && item.getFreeStock() <= 0) {
                        //We apply now the changes in all the cells of the row
                        for (int i = 0; i < getChildren().size(); i++) {
                            ((Labeled) getChildren().get(i)).setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, .25);");
                        }
                    } else {
                        for (int i = 0; i < getChildren().size(); i++) {
                            ((Labeled) getChildren().get(i)).setStyle("");
                        }
                        setStyle("");
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public SupplierOTIF getSupplier() {
        return supplier;
    }

    public void setSupplier(SupplierOTIF supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public void calculatePurchaseOrder() {

        supplier.calculateNumberOfDaysStock();

        supplier.calculateQTYToOrder();

        for (SupplierProductOTIF product : supplier.getOtifSupplierData()) {
            if (product.getSupplierPreference() == 1) {
                if (product.getQtyToOrder() > 0 || product.isException()) {
                    orderData.add(0, product);
                } else {
                    orderData.add(product);
                }
            }
        }

        orderTable.setItems(orderData);

    }

    public void updatePurchaseOrderValue() {
        double totalValue = 0.0;
        for (SupplierProductOTIF product : orderData) {
            totalValue += (product.getQtyToOrder() * product.getSupplierCost());
        }
        orderValueLabel.setText("Order Value: £" + SalesHelper.round(new BigDecimal(totalValue), 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
    }

    @Override
    public void loadAndShowData() throws Exception {

        calculatePurchaseOrder();

        updatePurchaseOrderValue();

    }

}
```

Comment: can't detect anything obvious in the snippet, should work as expected - please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: thanks, but we don't want to see _all_ your code, just an example as described in the link (meaning that you should write something for the sole reason of showing it here to enable debugging :) Anyway, was puzzled enough to tweak one of my own examples - looks like the cells are not yet created when row.updateItem is called the first time, so no styling can be applied initially. Only after some change to the data (or re-use of rows) is triggered, the style is applied. Hmm ...

Comment: why don't you apply the style to the row (vs. its children)?

Comment: I second kleopatra, it seems like you should be applying the style to the `TableRow` rather than its `TableCell` children.

Comment: @Slaw one visual twirk I see with row styling is that also the free space of a row is colored. At OP, other options: set the data after the stage has been shown (nasty, might not get auto-sizing correct and might not update on updating styling-relevant properties of the data, didn't try) or let the cells style themselves: they have access to the row data, so enough info to do their job. Astonished ...

Comment: Thanks @kleopatra & Slaw. Setting it on the row worked perfect. I had read that you had to do it on the cell which is why I went for that approach.

Comment: glad it help :) Yeah, typically you do it on the cell - by the cell itself (not by the row it's contained in). Beware: if the data is updated, the row might not get updated which leads to loosing the styling if done on the row!

Comment: @kleopatra Thankfully this only a popup dialogue after computation so little need for data updates... If it wasn't for the TextFieldTableCell I'm using on one of the cells I would have applied it to every cell but this seems so cumbersome. Apologies that the code was not how you expected it, given my circumstances Im not sure it would have helped. Thanks for your help and pointing me in the right direction. I really appreciate it, this had me stumped for a good hour or maybe two!

Comment: No problem, this one had me stumped as well (my expection being the same as yours ;) on a side note: wondering why you use a TextFieldTableCell if the table is read-only?

Comment: @kleopatra Yea, when I was testing this I was surprised that update changes fired by the `ObservableList` didn't cause the `TableRow` to update. I ended up coming across [JDK-8187665](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187665) which, unfortunately, is still unresolved. As for the visual twirk, one could try and replicate part of the default CSS styling (by looking at `modena.css`) and just apply the custom color as the inner/inset background.

Comment: @Slaw my memory gets weaker, filed that one just about a year ago ;) This is slightly different, though: row's updateItem is called less frequent then I would expect.

Comment: @kleopatra the table has one editable cell (Qty To Order) hence the TextFieldTableCell. I’ve built a system which forecasts product sales using historic data. The table in question is the suggested order for a given supplier which can then be raised from this screen. In the majority of cases the computed order qty is pretty accurate and doesn’t need to be adjusted but I have given the user the ability to override the order qty for a given item should they feel the need. I used a row factory as I couldn’t work out how to override the updateItem method for the TextFieldTableCell cell factory.